# How to merge same array key as one but the value differently.?

Tags: php, arrays

How to merge same array key as one but the value differently.
I am using my codes to output the value as follows:

> Spanish Primera Division2016-17,2017-18 Copa Del Ray2016-17

But When I echo out the my codes then I am getting the output as follows:

> Spanish Primera Division2017-18 Copa Del Ray2016-17 Spanish Primera 
>   Division2016-17

Can you see Spanish Primera Division two times. I want this one time but the year two times.
Codes:

```
<?php
        $champion_team = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'football_league_team_name', true );
        $terms_competition = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'competition' );
        $terms_session = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'session' );
       $cc= array_merge($terms_competition, $terms_session);

       foreach ( $cc as $c) {
        # code...
        echo $c->name;
       }




?>
```

print_r output:

```
WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 6 [name] => Spanish Primera Division [slug] => spanish-primera-divisioj [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 6 [taxonomy] => competition [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 10 [filter] => raw ) 

WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 7 [name] => 2017-18 [slug] => 2017-18 [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 7 [taxonomy] => session [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 4 [filter] => raw ) 

WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 18 [name] => Copa Del Ray [slug] => copa-del-ray [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 18 [taxonomy] => competition [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 1 [filter] => raw ) 

WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 11 [name] => 2016-17 [slug] => 2016-17 [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 11 [taxonomy] => session [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 9 [filter] => raw ) 

WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 6 [name] => Spanish Primera Division [slug] => spanish-primera-divisioj [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 6 [taxonomy] => competition [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 10 [filter] => raw ) 

WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 11 [name] => 2016-17 [slug] => 2016-17 [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 11 [taxonomy] => session [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 9 [filter] => raw )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add them

```
$cc= $terms_competition + $terms_session;
```

Any keys that are not present in `$terms_competition` are added from `$terms_session`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $champion_team = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'football_league_team_name', true );
    $terms_competition = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'competition' );
    $terms_session = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'session' );
   $cc= array_merge($terms_competition, $terms_session);

   $temp = array();
   foreach ( $cc as $c) {
    # code...

     if(!in_array($temp)) {
      echo $c->name;
      $temp[] = $c->term_id;
     }
   }
```

Comment: shows: Warning: in_array() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\testtheme\framework\team\honour.php on line 48

Answer (score -1):

```html
You can try like this :

With array_unique

foreach (array_unique($data) as $d) {
 // Do stuff with $d ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. In this way?